# Comparar si dos variables son iguales

Tags: arduino

Tengo este programa que me lee datos provenientes de un plc para después enviarlos a una base de datos, el valor recibido cambia hasta que un botón es presionado, por lo cual si no es presionado el botón se mantiene el mismo valor y por lo cual ese valor se envía varias veces. como pudiera comprar el dato anterior con el nuevo para saber si son o no son iguales, si son iguales no enviar el dato y si el valor cambia enviar el dato.¿Cómo podría hacer la comparación?

Código:

```
int result =  node.readInputRegisters(address, bytesQty);

if (result != 0) {
  USB.println("Communication error");
  delay(1000);
} 
else 
{ 
  USB.print(F("Read value: "));
  USB.println(node.getResponseBuffer(0));
  frame.createFrame(ASCII);  

frame.addSensor(SENSOR_MODBUS_HOLDING_REGS, (int) node.getResponseBuffer(0));
  delay(1000);
}
delay(1000); 
node.clearResponseBuffer();


error = xbee802.send( RX_ADDRESS, frame.buffer, frame.length );   

if( error == 0 )
{
  USB.println(F("Envio Correcto"));
  Utils.blinkGreenLED();  
}
else 
{
  USB.println(F("Envio Erroneo"));
  Utils.blinkRedLED();
}

delay(60000);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No esta todo el código para poder entenderlo mejor, pero tienes que guardar el valor anterior en una variable para poder ver si ha cambiado. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo

```
setup()
{
    int anterior = 0;
    int actual = 0;
}

loop()
{
    actual = LeerDato(); //(int) node.getResponseBuffer(0) no se si seria esto.
    if(actual != anterior)
    {
        EnviarDato();//error=xbee802.send(RX_ADDRESS,frame.buffer,frame.length);
        anterior = actual;
        if( error == 0 )
        {
            USB.println(F("Envio Correcto"));
            Utils.blinkGreenLED();  
        }
        else 
        {
            USB.println(F("Envio Erroneo"));
            Utils.blinkRedLED();
        }
    }
}
```

No deberías utilizar `delay` porque si cambia mientras esta en un `delay no lo sabrás.